# buscar las 3 fechas más antiguas en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema con una consulta.
La tabla tiene los siguientes campos:

```
Tabla1
--------+-----------+---------+------------------
Id      | Inicio    | Fin     | Descripcion
--------+-----------+---------+------------------
```

Y las reglas son:

- Si algún inicio o fin es = '0000-00-00' que me devuelva que hay fechas con ese valor.
- Si algún inicio o fin es = '0001-01-01' que me devuelva que hay fechas con ese valor
- Y aparte necesito la fecha más antiguas que no sean '0000-00-00' y '0000-00-000' agrupada por descripción.

¿Es posible esto?

Ejemplo con datos:

```
Tabla1
--------+------------+------------+------------------
Id      | Inicio     | Fin        | Descripcion
--------+------------+------------+------------------
1       - 0000-00-00 - 0000-00-00 - 1
2       - 0001-01-01 - 0001-01-01 - 1
3       - 0000-00-00 - 0000-00-00 - 1
3       - 2016-10-20 - 0000-00-00 - 1
4       - 2016-07-10 - 0000-00-00 - 1
5       - 0000-00-00 - 2016-11-20 - 1
6       - 0000-00-00 - 2016-10-30 - 1
7       - 0000-00-00 - 0000-00-00 - 2
8       - 0001-01-01 - 0001-01-01 - 2
9       - 0000-00-00 - 0000-00-00 - 2
10      - 2016-10-20 - 0000-00-00 - 2
11      - 2016-07-10 - 0000-00-00 - 2
12      - 0000-00-00 - 2016-11-20 - 2
13      - 0000-00-00 - 2016-10-30 - 2
```

Lo que debería mostrar sería:

> Producto 1 posee fechas en 0000-00-00, 0001-01-01, 2016-07-10 (Inicio)
>   y 2016-10-30 (Fin)

Y producto 2 lo mismo.

Tengo la siguiente consulta, pero no funciona correctamente:

```
SELECT MIN(inicio), MIN(fin), descripcion
FROM tabla1
GROUP BY descripcion
```

En PHP tengo lo siguiente:

```
if ($f['inicio'] != '0001-01-01' AND $f['inicio'] != '0000-00-00' AND $f['fin'] == '0000-00-00')
                {
                if ($diferencia >= 3)
                    {
                    echo '<td>"Tareas atrasadas!!"</td>';
                    }
                if ($diferencia <= 2)
                    {
                    echo '<td>"Sin atraso"</td>';
                    }
                }
                if ($f['ultimarealizazion'] == '0001-01-01')
                    {
                    echo '<td>"Sin atraso"</td>';
                    }
                else
                    {
                    echo '<td>"Sin asignaciones"</td>';
```

Comment: Hola Pepemujica. Gracias por la pregunta. Por favor toma en cuenta lo que dice la pagina de ayuda [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir __un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema__ y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.*.  De modo, que sería bueno si compartes las consultas SQL que has intentado hasta ahora, aunque no funcionen correctamente.

Comment: Hola, no es una tarea, ya no voy al colegio xD. Estoy armando un sistema de stock para algunos productos que tengo y necesito obtener estas fechas. Lo que tengo, pero no funciona OK es esto: SELECT MIN(inicio), MIN(fin), descripcion
FROM tabla1
GROUP BY descripcion

Comment: Jeje. Es cierto que no dijistes que era tarea, pero el principio mas general es que se aprecia cuando el que pregunta comparte lo que ya han intentado. Demuestra esfuerzo de tu parte y dignifica la comunidad que desea ayudarte. En este caso, sería bueno que modifiques la pregunta directamente para incluir la sentencia SQL, mas bien que dejarlo en el comentario. Asi todos lo veran mas claro.

Comment: Listo, agregué la consulta y el código PHP que utiliza los resultados de la misma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Yo usaría lo consulta siguiente:</strike> (prefiero el SQL que propongo más abajito)

```
select producto,
       coalesce(max(case when inicio_o_fin = '0000-00-00' then 1 end), 0) as tiene_0,
       coalesce(max(case when inicio_o_fin = '0001-01-01' then 1 end), 0) as tiene_1,
       min(case when inicio_o_fin not in ('0000-00-00', '0001-01-01')
                     and tipo = 'inicio'
                then inicio_o_fin end) as min_inicio,
       min(case when inicio_o_fin not in ('0000-00-00', '0001-01-01')
                     and tipo = 'fin' 
                then inicio_o_fin end) as min_fin
  from (select descripcion as producto,
               inicio as inicio_o_fin,
               'inicio' as tipo
          from Tabla1
         union all
        select descripcion as producto,
               fin as inicio_o_fin,
               'fin' as tipo
          from Tabla1) t
 group by producto
 order by producto
```

En este caso, el resultado sería:

```
producto  tiene_0  tiene_1   min_inicio   min_fin
--------  -------  -------   ----------   ----------
   1         1        1      2016-07-10   2016-10-30
   2         1        1      2016-07-10   2016-10-30
```

Para las columnas `tiene_0` y `tiene_1`, el resultado es `0` si no existe `0000-00-00` (o `0001-01-01` según el caso), y `1` si existe.

Con esos resultados, debería ser fácil para ti de usar tu código en PHP para transformar los datos en la frase:

> Producto 1 posee fechas en 0000-00-00, 0001-01-01, 2016-07-10 (Inicio) y 2016-10-30 (Fin)

**Edición: Mejor respuesta**

Por favor, olvida la sentencia que sugerí arriba (aunque la voy a dejar para que puedas comparar). Prefiero la siguiente, que es mucho más sencilla, y solo necesita recorrer la tabla una vez:

```
select descripcion as producto,
       coalesce(max(case when inicio = '0000-00-00' or fin = '0000-00-00' then 1 end), 0) as tiene_0,
       coalesce(max(case when inicio = '0001-01-01' or fin = '0001-01-01' then 1 end), 0) as tiene_1,
       min(case when inicio not in ('0000-00-00', '0001-01-01') then inicio end) as min_inicio,
       min(case when fin not in ('0000-00-00', '0001-01-01') then fin end) as min_fin
  from Tabla1
 group by descripcion
 order by producto
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Intenté implementarla en mi MYSQL me dice que with cte as( .... tiene un problema de sintaxis.. Para qué sirve esa parte?

Comment: @Pepemujica: Disculpa, se me olvida que MySQL no sabe manejar esa sintaxis que otros bases de datos si pueden. Ajusté la respuesta para que funcione en MySQL. Para tu informacion, esa sintaxis se llama una *expresión de tabla común* (comunmente abreviado *CTE* en inglés). Puedes leer mas al respecto aquí si te interesa: https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Funciona tal como esperaba. Aún no entiendo qué es lo que hace cada parte, pero voy a ir investigando. Saludos!

Comment: Muy bien. Estoy seguro que al examinar tranquilamente cada parte, podras ir aprendiendo nuevas técnicas. Si acaso hubiera algun aspecto específico del SQL que no logras entender aun después de investigarlo, no tengas pena en hacer una nueva pregunta en SOes al respecto. Puede que otras personas tengan la misma duda y tu pregunta les beneficie.

Comment: Despues de pensarlo un poco más, me doy cuenta que mi SQL es más complicado de lo necesario. Agregué otra sentencia SQL que es más sencilla y ofrece mejor rendimiento.

Comment: Ahora sí! es mucho más simple! :) me estaba volviendo loco tratando de usar JOINS con otras tablas jaja. Muchas gracias nuevamente!!

Answer (score 0):

La consulta

```
SELECT MIN(inicio), MIN(fin), descripcion
FROM tabla1
WHERE inicio != '0000-00-00' and inicio != '0001-01-01' and fin != '0000-00-00' and fin != '0001-01-01'
GROUP BY descripcion
```

debería darte las fechas mínimas "reales".

Para saber si hay registros con '0000-00-00' por ejemplo, podrías usar una sub-consulta:

```
SELECT MIN(inicio), MIN(fin), descripcion,
    (select count(*) from tabla1 B where A.descripcion = B.descripcion and inicio == '0000-00-00') as count_inicio_0
FROM tabla1 A
WHERE inicio != '0000-00-00' and inicio != '0001-01-01' and fin != '0000-00-00' and fin != '0001-01-01'
GROUP BY descripcion
```

y lo mismo para las otras (inicio todo en uno, fin todo en cero y en uno). Así, si `count_inicio_0` es mayor que `0`, quiere decir que hay algún inicio con '0000-00-00'.

Comment: Me devuelve vacío esa consulta, no logro entender del todo la sub query